# How to stop PHP DOM from auto-escaping character references?

Tags: php, dom, character-encoding

...or how to do it another way?

I'm creating a select box using [DOMDocument](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php).

```
$field = $this->dom->createElement('select');
$optgroup = $this->dom->createElement('optgroup');

foreach($options as $v) {
   $option = $this->dom->createElement('option');
   $option->setAttribute('value', $v);
   $option->appendChild($this->dom->createTextNode($v));

   $optgroup->appendChild($option);
}

$field->appendChild($optgroup);
```

Where `$options` is an array of character references pre-loaded from an icon font:

```
array('&#33;', '&#34;', '&#35;', '&#36;', ...);
```

I need my output to look like this:

```
<select>
  <optgroup>
    <option value="&#33;">&#33;</option>
    <option value="&#34;">&#34;</option>
    <option value="&#35;">&#35;</option>
    ...
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

However, using the DOM methods, it auto escapes all the character references:

```
<option value="&amp;#33;">&amp;#33;</option>
```

How can I prevent that from happening?

**NOTE:** [`createEntityReference`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.createentityreference.php) does not work for this as that method only supports entity references and not character references. Using it causes a fatal error for 'Invalid character error'.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try a documentFragment instead, and stuff in some pre-made HTML:

```
$frag = $dom->createDocumentFragment();
$frag->loadHTML('<option value="&#33;">&#33;</option>');

$dom->appendChild($frag);
```

DOM is handy for manipulating an existing tree, but it's an incredible PAIN to build a new tree using nothing but DOM operations. Sometime's it's just easier to build your html/xml with plain string operations and then shove the whole string into DOM in one operation.

Comment: `createDocumentFragement` doesn't have a `loadHTML` method. http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocumentfragment.php

Comment: Shoot... always a catch. It does extend domnode, which has a domdocument as an attribute. might be able to hook into that. It also DOES have appendXML(), which might do the trick. no idea how strict it'll be with character entities.

Comment: It's been a while, but I never came back to say this ultimately worked, just using the `appendXML()` method.

Comment: This answer doesn't work... (like Michael said, `DOMDocumentFragment` doesn't have an `loadHTML()` method)